# Quickly reverse layer order of objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I want to perform some operation like this:

Change objects order from:

```
object 1
object 2
object 3
```

to:

```
object 3
object 2
object 1
```

I see there is [an option in Photoshop that can reverse the front-to-back order of multiple layers with a click](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/is-it-possible-to-control-layer-order-in-an-illustrator-stroke), I also see there is a "Reverse Order" option in the layer panel of Illustrator, but it is always greyed out. (wonder when it is useful)

Is there anyway to reverse object front-to-back order quickly without manually moving the objects individually? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, just figured it out after reading the official guide and some experimenting:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stacking-objects.html

Needed to click the object at the top within the layer panel, then hold SHIFT and click the object at the very back, finally click the then clickable "Reverse Order" option. (Not using Command/Ctrl as mentioned in the guide!!)

Comment: Thanks Pete, glad you found it yourself. Can you accept your own answer, so other users will know the issue has been solved. Thanks.